# how to change image background color and save it with new background color

Tags: android

I have an application that removes the image background and set a new blue background colour and save it but when I open an image it shows black background.

How I can save this with a blue background ?.

```
   imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));

   BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
   BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/Passport Photo123");
    dir.mkdirs();
    String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
    File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    try {
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Photo Saved at: " + outFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code :-

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
```

If it not works than the problem must be elsewhere.